# Issue with iterating over DataFrame rows in Spark Scala and extracting values from a CSV file

Tags: scala, loops, csv, apache-spark

I'm working on a project with Apache Spark in Scala and I'm facing an issue while trying to iterate over the rows of a DataFrame and extract values from columns of a CSV file.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object ExampleDataFrameIteration {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("ExampleDataFrameIteration").getOrCreate()

    // Load the CSV file
    val df = spark.read.csv("path/to/file.csv")

    // Iterate over the rows
    df.foreach { row =>
      // Extract values from columns
      val number = row.getAs[String]("number")
      val account = row.getAs[String]("account")

      // Show the values
      println(s"number: $number, Account: $account")
    }

    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

However, when running the code, I'm not getting the expected output in the console. It seems like the println is not displaying anything, even though the CSV file has valid content.

I have already checked the path of the CSV file and I'm sure it's correct. Additionally, I confirmed that the CSV file has a header row with the column names 'number' and 'account'.

Could someone help me identify what might be causing this issue and how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The job triggered by Spark is initiated from the driver and the actions run on the executor and the returns the result back to the driver due to the distributed nature of running the application.

This means if you want to fetch the result in the form of a `println` then, you must use an action such as `collect` to bring the result back to the driver node.

If you supplement the `foreach` action with `collect` as shown below, you should be able to see the data as expected:

```py
df.collect.foreach { row =>
      // Extract values from columns
      val number = row.getAs[String]("number")
      val account = row.getAs[String]("account")

      // Show the values
      println(s"number: $number, Account: $account")
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test it locally, set `.config("spark.master", "local")` and then it should print in the console when executor (in this case local) runs the tasks.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("ExampleDataFrameIteration").config("spark.master", "local").getOrCreate()
```

Logs will look something as shown below (considering `INFO` level `org.apache.spark` is turned on)

```
Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
CodeGenerator: Code generated in ... ms
<THEN the println from the code>
```

If you are not running locally, check the logs (stdout logs) of the executor instance.

`foreach` action does not return anything, it is usually used to do some operation on each partition from the executor itself (i.e database interaction using `foreachPartition` etc). So the println in your example should print in the executor log (stdout).